# Install freeipa server on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, samba

How to install freeipa server on the ubuntu 14.04? Where can I find freeipa package for ubuntu? Thanks.

I have tried this:

```
root@stage-app-40a:~#  apt-get install freeipa-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package freeipa-server
root@stage-app-40a:~#
```

I have added repository:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freeipa/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/sssd/updates/ubuntu trusty main
```

Answer (score 2):

**freeipa-server** is finally a standard module to be installed in the 16.04 LTS version without any additional PPA's!

```
sudo apt-get install freeipa-server
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is a work in progress. The project page is [here](https://launchpad.net/freeipa)

You might be able to install the debian package available [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/net/freeipa-server) but **I wouldn't attempt this on a production machine** as there's a long list of dependencies some of which may be unresolvable. The advisable thing to do is to wait until the developers finish their work.